# sqlquery insert data from one table to other with id from columnname

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an old database with some complex joining of the data. As given below

**Subjects**

```html
Id                  Name
-------------------------------
1                   Math
2                   Science
3                   English
```

**Results**

```html
Id  StudentId  Math  MathMax  Science  ScienceMax  English  EnglishMax   TotalMarks  Max
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    81        5      10       6          10          3        10          14         30
2    82        8      10       8          10          9        10          25         30
3    83        7      10       8          10          7        10          22         30
```

Now I am trying to convert it to more easy and readable database. So I come up with the tables like
**Results**

```html
ResultId  StudentId  TotalMarks  MaxMarks
-------------------------------------------
1          81          14          30
2          82          25          30
3          83          22          30
```

**ResultDetails**

```html
Id    ResultId      SubjectId      Marks      MaxMarks
--------------------------------------------------------
1      1              1              5          10
2      1              2              6          10
3      1              3              7          10
& so one
```

Now the real question I can insert data in the new Results table but I am confused on the second table. I can't understand that how to pass column name of one table and get the id of that name from second table and insert it in the third one.
I am trying on but can't understand the right commands to achieve this. My database already have 50000+ records and I have to merge them according to this new tables.

Comment: Are there only 3 subjects in your original table? Or are there more and this is just kind of a sample?

Comment: There are atleast 10 subjects in the original table. Its an example of those tables. Original tables contains more columns like exam details, grades etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a one-off conversion of data, and you've already populated your new Results table, something as simple as the following should work:

```
INSERT INTO ResultDetails(ResultId, SubjectId, Marks, MaxMarks)
SELECT 
    R.StudentId, 
    1 AS SubjectId, 
    OldR.Math AS Marks, 
    OldR.MathMax AS MaxMarks
FROM Results R
INNER JOIN OldResults OldR ON R.StudentId = OldR.StudentId

INSERT INTO ResultDetails(ResultId, SubjectId, Marks, MaxMarks)
SELECT 
    R.StudentId, 
    2 AS SubjectId, 
    OldR.Science AS Marks, 
    OldR.ScienceMax AS MaxMarks
FROM Results R
INNER JOIN OldResults OldR ON R.StudentId = OldR.StudentId

INSERT INTO ResultDetails(ResultId, SubjectId, Marks, MaxMarks)
SELECT 
    R.StudentId, 
    3 AS SubjectId, 
    OldR.English AS Marks, 
    OldR.EnglishMax AS MaxMarks
FROM Results R
INNER JOIN OldResults OldR ON R.StudentId = OldR.StudentId
```

It's not a very elegant solution, but it doesn't need to be for a one-off conversion.

Comment: What if he has 40 subjects?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But according to this I have to create single query for each subject. 
Its a good solution if your have limited numbers of subjects. I tried it with some changes like joining with other tables. After that data inserted in new tables successfully. Now have to check if data is inserted correctly or not. 
Will mark as answer asap its done.

Comment: OK, cool. I was assuming the schema you posted covered all of the subjects, given that it had an explicit column in the table for each subject.

Comment: As of my checking so far. The data is looking good. The posted data is just for example. Original tables contains more data like exam details, grades etc.

So if someone have the same problem with limited numbers of subject(or any other table), you can use this.
Thanks Alan!!